# I want to show every opened window in POP_OS as separated icon in taskpar or docker. is that doable?

Tags: linux, docker, pop-os

[image: Figure Example]

For example I want this windows of Brave Browser to be separated. And not grouped like in one icon.

Comment: Try these steps: [ungroup apps in dock](https://askubuntu.com/a/1347545/1086345). If that doesn't work, let me know

Comment: It's useful but it changes the Main UI of docker which I love actually .. I just need the same UI with separated windows only that not more not less.